# Qgis server : install QWC2 and Lizmap on the same server?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-server, lizmap, qwc2

I succeed in installing qgis server on our Debian server. Before starting on the installation and documentation of QWC2 and Lizmap, we would have been interested in a small comparison of these two solutions. In a test perspective, is it possible to have these 2 solutions installed on the same Debian server? (for information, we have apache as web server). Or is it unadviced to attempt this double installation (risk of conflicts in particular)?

Answer (score 2):

The only common part between these two projects is QGIS server and the web server (Nginx/Apache).

I don't see any blocker using the same QGIS server, for testing purpose. The Lizmap QGIS server plugin shouldn't interfere much in QGIS server.

For Nginx/Apache, you can setup two virtual hosts, each one running the server application you want.

It's two distinct applications running on a server.

I'm talking about a Lizmap side. I don't know much about QWC2.